# Pseudodifferential operator associated to a self-adjoint extension of a symmetric operator on an incomplete manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $D$ be the Dirac operator acting on a spinor bundle $S$ over a complete Riemannian manifold $M$. Then $D$ is an essentially self-adjoint operator on $L^2(S)$.

Suppose there is a compact subset $K\subseteq M$ and a constant $c>0$ such that $D^2\geq c$ on $U:=M\backslash K$, in the sense that

$$\langle Ds,s\rangle_{L^2}\geq c$$

for all $s\in C_c^\infty(S|_U)$.

Since the Riemannian submanifold $U$ may not be complete, the restriction of $D$ to $U$,
$$D_U:L^2(S|_{U})\rightarrow L^2(S|_{U}),$$
is symmetric but perhaps not essentially self-adjoint. However, because $D_U^2\geq c$, there exists a self-adjoint Friedrichs extension $E$ of $D_U^2$. Thus we can use the functional calculus for self-adjoint operators to define the bounded operator 
$$A=(\sqrt{E}+i)^{-1}:L^2(S|_U)\rightarrow L^2(S|_U).$$
Meanwhile, we also have the operator
$$B=(D+i)^{-1}:L^2(S)\rightarrow L^2(S)$$
defined by functional calculus of $D$.

I would like to understand $A$ better and compare $A$ to $B$.

**Q1:** Let $s\in C_c^\infty(S|_U)$. Then is $As$ a smooth section of $S|_U$?

**Q2:** Can $A$ be thought of as pseudodifferential operator of order $-1$?

**Q3:** Is $As=Bs$ for $s\in C_c^\infty(S|_U)$?

**Q4:** Is $B$ an extension of $A$ from $L^2(S|_U)$ to $L^2(S)$?

It seems to me that Q4$\implies$Q3$\implies$Q2$\implies$Q1. I suspect the answer to Q2, and hence Q1, to be yes, but the answers to Q3 and Q4 to be no, because I'd guess that $\text{supp}(Bs)$ could be larger than $U$ for general $s\in C_c^\infty(S|_U)$. So I'm suspecting that $A$ and $B$ are two different pseudodifferential operators, but I would appreciate any expert opinions on this. An example that illustrates the difference between $A$ and $B$ would be helpful too.

Comment: It seems to me that $D$ has eigenvalues of both signs, whereas $\sqrt E$ is positive. Hence $As\ne Bs$ in general.